# How to apply the principles of CleanCode to the else expression in my code?

Tags: php, if-statement

How we remove the unnecessary else condition form below code we have also keep the code which is inside else statement but I don't wants to use else statement.

```
public function execute(array $responses)
{
    foreach ($responses as $response) {
        if (!$response) {
            $this->callbackSBDL = $this->taskSchema;
            $this->generateTask();
        } else {
            $this->queueHandler->findCompleted($this->taskSchema['tag']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to use `else` code then why `else` is unnecessary?

Comment: Suresh, you received two answers on the same day as asking this, but I cannot see that you have responded to the kind volunteers who have helped you. Would you do that now?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see why you would want to omit your else, but you could do something along these lines, with [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

```
public function execute(array $responses){
    foreach ($responses as $response) {
        //if response, do whatever you need to do, then continue to the next item in your list.
        if($response){
            $this->queueHandler->findCompleted($this->taskSchema['tag']);
            continue;
        }
        //this will only run if response isn't true, because we explicitly check and then skip ahead if response is true
        $this->callbackSBDL = $this->taskSchema;
        $this->generateTask();
    }
}
```

Personally, from a clean code standpoint, I'm of the opinion that if / else is more verbose and easily apparent to anyone reading the code what the objective and purpose is, whereas ternary operators or things like the above code require the reader to actually read all the steps in the code, and while it's still fairly simple to see the purpose, requires more effort to read and understand than the initial if / else.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine course of action to take depending on all possible values the $response variable, and write an "if" statement to cover each. In your example, it looks like you only need to determine if $response is "falsey", so you could do...

```
public function execute(array $responses)
{
    foreach ($responses as $response) {
        if (!$response) {
            $this->callbackSBDL = $this->taskSchema;
            $this->generateTask();
        }
        if ($response) {
           $this->queueHandler->findCompleted($this->taskSchema['tag']);
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd prefer to explicitly state under what circumstances the first "if" statement should be executed, along the lines of.....

```
public function execute(array $responses)
{
    foreach ($responses as $response) {
        if (false === $response || null === $response || 0 === $response) {
            $this->callbackSBDL = $this->taskSchema;
            $this->generateTask();
        }
        if ($response) {
           $this->queueHandler->findCompleted($this->taskSchema['tag']);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, doing things this way means you have to ensure that your "if" statements cover every possible value for $response.